# How i random this query with premium always on top

Tags: mysql

Sample data:

```
+--------------+------------+
|product_price | premium    |
+--------------+------------+
|         5000 | Premium    |
|          600 | Premium    |
|          800 | free       |
|          780 | free       |
|         2500 | free       |
|           50 | free       |
+--------------+------------+
```

The query:

```
SELECT  `a`.`product_name`, 
    `b`.`name`, 
    `a`.`product_images`, 
    `a`.`slug`, 
    `a`.`product_type`, 
    `a`.`product_price`,
    `a`.`premium` 
    FROM (`directory_product` a) JOIN `directory_items` b ON `b`.`id` = `a`.`id_directory` 
    ORDER BY `a`.`premium` DESC  LIMIT 6
```

thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ORDER BY RAND() + CASE WHEN premium = 'Premium' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you want `Premium` value from `premium` column on top ?

Then

```
order by case when premium = 'Premium' then 0 else 1 end
         ,premium
```